# How to make sure contracts in DbC being tested before rollout?

Tags: testing, design-by-contract

How do you make sure the contracts you defined for your software components using Design by Contract (DbC) are being tested at some point?

Shall I write unit tests for every single contract I define?

One benefit I see in DbC vs. isolated testing of single units is that I'm able to make sure the contract works between real collaborators. But how can I make sure the contracts are being tested before I rollout the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write a program that simulates users of your application, i.e. a bot. Startup your application with contracts enabled and have the bots exercise the app.
You can implement randomized behavior in your bots to have them exercise a larger set of use cases and edge cases.
Personally I often extend bots I write to verify performance to enable the sort of testing you're after.

Comment: So basically you are testing your contracts indirectly using any sort of integration testing?

Comment: Sort of. Except that randomized behavior makes it more likely that use cases you haven't explicitly thought about are executed.

Comment: Also, you should run the tests with code coverage turned on on the server side to make sure that you're not missing any use cases.